# Get parent/container of text node

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm using a [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) with the `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT` filter to find [`Text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) nodes in a DOM. I need to check some things regarding the element that contains the text node, is it possible to do this with my current `NodeFilter`, or do I need to use `NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT` and check the text content of each node instead?

`textNode.parentNode` and `textNode.parentElement` yield `null`

Comment: null or undefined? I can't see how a textNode could have no parent - perhaps if you showed some minimal, complete and verifiable example that demonstrates this bizarre state, we could help you

Comment: `null`. I'll try to extract the relevant code and edit my question

Comment: the only way I can get an **actual** textNode to have a null parentElement/parentNode is when you create it using `document.createTextNode` before appending it to another node

Comment: Hmm, tried to run some relevant code outside the app and it worked fine. I'll look into if we're using `document.createTextNode` anywhere.

Comment: Doesn't look like `document.createTextNode` is being used anywhere.. The plot thickens

Comment: Turns out the reason the text nodes' `.parentNode` was `null` was because I checked them at a later time in their lifespan - when they had been removed from the DOM - by logging the text node, revealing in element panel, and checking it with the console. If I logged the `node.parentNode` directly from the code, the parent was there. My bad.